# UICollectionView Bring Item to center position

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have used collectionview to show models as well as years and the user can swipe the cells.

The cell which is selected would be positioned to center not depending on number of items.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**SOL 1:**

```
collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
```

**SOL 2:**
     I suggest you add empty items at the beginning and end. So the user can scroll the first and last visible item to the centre.

Comment: Or `.CenteredVertically` for vertical collection view.

Comment: I have already tried this,but the elements are left alligned,suppose i have 2 objects then that objects starts from left not from center,so if there is any other sol.

Comment: @Diksha I suggest you add empty items at beginning and end. So user can  scroll the first and last visible item to the center.

Comment: @Diksha Don't forget to ignore empty items selection.

Comment: i guess it will be bit complicated to implement this

Comment: @Diksha Or add header and footer? This is simple.

Comment: how will this solve my problem by adding header and footer

Comment: @Diksha You can scroll the first item to center by this.

Comment: it worked by adding header and footer to collectionview

Comment: can you please help me out in blurring the texts as shown in imge

Comment: @Lumialxk can you edit your answer with above comments so that it will helpful to the community. Impressed with the solution.Up-voted.

Comment: @diksha :- Don't put app screen shot directly here , you are breaking companies privacy policies :p